# why CLLocationManager always returns true?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, viewdidload

I am using `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` function to get the status whether location service is enabled or not. I kept code in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    NSLog(@"No");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Yes");
}
```

When I am running this app first time it returns `Yes`. Why? It should return me `No`. This is the case when I did not select "Allow" or "Don't allow" options. Means I neither allow nor don't allow but in `viewDidLoad` I got `Yes`.

Now I select "Don't allow" and again load the same `viewController`. At this time at least it should return me `No`, but still I got `Yes`. Why?

So much of confusion with `CLLocationManager`.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra's answer is correct, this methods only tells about general state of location services on *device*. If you want to know whether *your application* is allowed to use them, you have to use `authorizationStatus` : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`locationServicesEnabled` returns whether location service is enabled on settings.. If it is enabled in settings, this function returns `YES` all the time..

from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/locationServicesEnabled)

> **locationServicesEnabled**
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether location services are enabled on the device.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The user can enable or disable location services from the Settings
>   application by toggling the Location Services switch in General.
>
> You should check the return value of this method before starting
>   location updates to determine whether the user has location services
>   enabled for the current device. If this method returns NO and you
>   start location updates anyway, the Core Location framework prompts the
>   user to confirm whether location services should be reenabled.

Whether or not user allowed/rejected app permission (in the alertview) doesn't affect the return value of this method.

If you want to know whether user has given application permission to access location, you can use [authorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus).